# Laravel 5.2 Route Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my home.blade.php I have the below code

```
<a href="{{ route('tasks.index') }}" class="btn btn-info">View Tasks</a>
<a href="{{ route('tasks.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Task</a>
```

then in the routes.php I have the following,

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@home'
]);

Route::get('/index', [
    'as' => 'index',
    'uses' => 'TasksController@index'
]);

Route::get('/create', [
    'as' => 'create',
    'uses' => 'TasksController@create'
]);
```

Why am I having this error for http://localhost:8000/

Route [tasks.index] not defined. (View: D:\wamp\www\test1\resources\views\pages\home.blade.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error

> Route [tasks.index] not defined. (View:
>   D:\wamp\www\test1\resources\views\pages\home.blade.php)

It's because you've named it `index` not `tasks.index`, so either change the name from `index` to `task.index` in route declaration or use `index` when referencing the route in your `href` attribute. Now you have this:

```
Route::get('/index', [
    'as' => 'index', // index is the name here so use the name as it is
    'uses' => 'TasksController@index'
]);
```

Same for `tasks.create`:

```
Route::get('/create', [
    'as' => 'create', // Name is "create" not "tasks.create"
    'uses' => 'TasksController@create'
]);
```

It would be better if you use a group for naming like (For V-5.1 and greater):

```
Route::group(['as' => 'tasks.'], function () {

    Route::get('/index', [
        'as' => 'index', // Now you can usee 'tasks.index'
        'uses' => 'TasksController@index'
    ]);

    Route::get('/create', [
        'as' => 'create', // Now you can usee 'tasks.create'
        'uses' => 'TasksController@create'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because Laravel couldn't find any routes named `tasks.index` or `tasks.create`. This is because you named your routes as `index` and `create` and `home`.

So if you want a link to point to the URL: `/tasks`, you have to link to that route using it's name.

ie: the url will be `route('index')`. 
This is taken from the route:

As you can see from the `routes.php` file, `'as'=>'index'` is the name of the route and this is what you should call.

So the link become:

```
<a href="{{ route('index') }}" class="btn btn-info">View Tasks</a>
<a href="{{ route('create') }}" class="btn btn-info">CreateTasks</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As The Alpha said it's better to group the routes. Also you can chain methods like this

```
    Route::group(['as' => 'tasks.'], function () 

    {

    Route::get('/index', 'TasksController@index')->name(index);

    Route::get('/create', 'TasksController@create')->name(create);

    });
```

After defining the routes this was you can use route function

```
{{ route('tasks.index') }}
{{ route('tasks.create') }}
```

Or if you prefer not to group the routes you can do like this:

```
Route::get('/index', 'TasksController@index')->name(tasks.index);

Route::get('/create', 'TasksController@create')->name(tasks.create);
```

Now you can use :

```
<a href="{{ route('tasks.index') }}" class="btn btn-info">View Tasks</a>
<a href="{{ route('tasks.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Task</a>
```

You can see what routes you have and their names running this command in the project folder:

```
php artisan route:list
```